# Center sub menu items jQuery Mega Drop Down Menu Plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there a way to center all the sub menu items in the jQuery Mega Drop Down Menu Plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the menu you are referring to: 
http://jquery-plugins.net/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu-plugin

To center sub menu items, I would add:

```
    #mega-menu-1 li .sub li{
         text-align: center;
    }
```